# How to remove specific field value in redux-form

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying to clear specific Field value in Redux-form, I tried but I am failed because I am new to React and redux. Could someone please tell me how to clear specific field value ?

**Code**

```
             <div className="space-2">
               <Field
                name="firstName"
                component={renderField}
                type="text"
                label="First Name"
                validate={isFieldRequired}

              />
            </div>
            <div className="space-2">
              <Field
                name="lastName"
                component={renderField}
                type="text"
                label="Last Name"
                validate={isFieldRequired}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="space-2">
              <Field
                name="email"
                component={renderField}
                type="email"
                label="Email Address"
                validate={isFieldRequired}
              />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux form then do it in the following ways:

```
import { change } from 'redux-form';

// write a function as below
fireFieldValueChange() {
  this.props.changeValue('loginForm', 'email', '');
}

// in your mapDispatchToProps
changeValue: (form, field, value) => dispatch(change(formName, fieldName, valueToBeSet)),
```

Hope, this helps you.